# How can I convert CLLocationManager.magneticHeading to radians?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, math, cllocationmanager

I am trying to covert the number of magneticHeading that I see, from 0 to 360, into radians so I can use CGPoint. However this code throws an error.

```
//Code to move on the X plane
let heading = self!.locManager.heading

let MagHeading = (heading?.magneticHeading)! * M_PI/180 //error
```

How can I covert this CLLocation value I get from the heading into a float so I can turn it into radians?
The error is that heading is nil. Yet without the conversion it still produces values

Comment: Don't you think it would be helpful to include the error in your question?

Comment: That syntax was automatically generated by Swift

Comment: You really need to spend time learning about Swift optionals. They are key to using Swift properly. Don't just slap `!` on various bits of code without knowing what it really means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actual problem and your question are absolutely different. You need to handle optional variable there... but you mentioned conversion between double/float to radian

try this... at least your error will be gone.

```
if let heading = self.locManager.heading {

    let MagHeading = (heading.magneticHeading) * M_PI/180
    print("MagHeading - \(MagHeading)")

}  else {

   print("heading is nil")

}
```

Comment: Why use `?` (or `!`) after `self`? `self` can't be `nil`.

Comment: In this case it can. It throws an error if not unwrapped.

Comment: @rmaddy The code is most likely in a closure with `[weak self]` attribute.

Comment: @timedwalnut try this code, I shared here and see result

Comment: @timedwalnut You really need to edit your question then to show more context and relevant code. And please show the complete, exact error message and point out the exact line causing the error.

Comment: @KrunalBhavsar Thanks for coming up with a solution given my the ambiguity of the context of my question